# Zoom content not screen with Magic Mouse

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, zoom

many windows users used to use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Scroll Wheel</kbd> for zooming in and out.

But in `macOS` this doesn't work. I can zoom with gestures using touchpad, but I mostly use `Magic Mouse`.

There is an option to enable zooming screen, but not the content in `Accessibility` settings. This is not what I am trying to get.

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> on the other hand works in some applications (in most applications I need), but this is keyboard combination, is there any way to get the same result as <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> but with Magic Mouse Scroll ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,i never saw Content before(too rush),,`CMD` + Magic mouse scroll in most cases doesn't increase the font size, 'zoom' in. Increasing the font size system wide isn't possible without setting it specifically for Applications (if you know the menu title) in keyboard shortcuts. However, you can emulate a system wide zoom in level with a double tap of the mouse (using magic mouse) by turning that system feature on in:

`System Preferences` > `Mouse` > `Smart Zoom`

But still Incase of screen,,Go to `System Preferences` > `Accessibility`, and in the list on the left click the item `"Zoom"`.

Then make sure that feature is enabled (checkmarked) in the pane on the right, and that Control has been set as the `modifier`.

Then Just hold down the [control] key, then slide your finger to the top or bottom of the mouse, and you’ll zoom in and out just like you would with a mouse scroll wheel.

Hope this solves your problem!